# flatten multiple rows in to 1 row using snowflake sql

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have a table like this:

```
id  col1 col2 col3 col4
1   Y    N    N    N  
1   N    N    Y    N
1   N    Y    N    N
1   N    N    N    N
```

i want it to look like this:

```
id col1 col2 col3 col4
1  Y    Y    Y    N
```

how can i do this

Comment: What is the data type of the columns?

Comment: they are strings

Answer (score 2):

You can use `MAX()`:

```
select id, max(col1), max(col2), max(col3), max(col4)
from t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value to want is not naturally high (and thus you can use MAX) or not naturally low (and thus use MIN) then you can and you are looking for a single state you can encode that
into

```
IFF(SUM(IFF(value = <target>,1,0)>0,<target>,<non-target>)
```

which really should be done via [BOOLOR_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/boolor_agg.html) (which has the exact example you have posted).

```
select id, boolor_agg(col1), boolor_agg(col2), boolor_agg(col3), maxboolor_agg(col4)
from t
group by id;
```

Otherwise if you really how some more complex value aggregation beyond the assumed `logical or` it appears you want, you will need to explain more.